# Getting custom program error 0x16 on Raydium after burning LP tokens

Tags: transactions, error, liquiditypool, failed, raydium

[image]I created a liquity pool on Raydium a few days ago and scheduled the pool to be launched 3 days from now. Yesterday I burned the LP (on Sol-incinerator) and since then I noticed there are a lot of error messages under my transactions on SolScan.  and keep getting a bunch of error codes.
I may be wrong but feel like this started happening once I issued a burn on Sol's incinerator.

the error is:

#6 Raydium Liquidity Pool V4 instruction

> Program log: Error: InvalidStatus
> Program Raydium Liquidity Pool V4  consumed 12734 of 1349495 compute units
> Program returned error: custom program error: 0x16

Comment: Im also having the same issue, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share a transaction link? Most likely you're trying to interact with a AMM that is still uninitialized.

The AMM status defined by Raydium are:

- Uninitialized
- Initialized
- Disabled
- WithdrawOnly
- LiquidityOnly: pool only can add or remove liquidity, can't swap and plan orders
- OrderBookOnly: pool only can add or remove liquidity and plan orders, can't swap
- SwapOnly: pool only can add or remove liquidity and swap, can't plan orders
- WaitingTrade: pool status after created and will auto update to SwapOnly during swap after open_time